# Programatically adding webparts to a page in sandbox

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, splimitedwebpartmanager

I've successfully implemented code to add web parts to web part zones in code using WebPartManager's in other projects.

Now that I'm working in a sandbox solution, VS can't seem to recognise necessary parts of the api such as SPWebPartCollection or GetLimitedWebPartManager.

My question really is why? Is this a limitation of a sandbox solution? If so, how else can I achieve the above (title)?

Just as a bit more context - this will ultimately be deployed to SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have discovered SPLimitedWebPartManager is not availabe on Sandboxed solutions.

Snippet from [Waldek Mastykarz blog](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-provisioning-web-parts-wiki-pages-sandboxed-solutions/):

> **Inconvenient provisioning Web Parts instances from Sandboxed Solutions**
>
> One of the challenges when working with Sandboxed Solutions is how to
>   provision Web Parts instances to pages. If you have done this before
>   in a Farm Solution you know, that in order to add a Web Part to a page
>   programmatically in SharePoint you have to retrieve the instance of
>   the SPLimitedWebPartManager class and use it to add the instance of a
>   Web Part to a page. Unfortunately, as the SDK mentions, the
>   SPLimitedWebPartManager class is not available in Sandboxed Solutions
>   which means that you cannot programmatically add a Web Part to a page
>   from within a Sandboxed Solution.
>
> Luckily the programmatic approach isn’t the only option that
>   SharePoint offers for adding Web Parts to pages. It turns out that
>   there is a declarative approach as well, which is just perfect for
>   when you need to provision a Web Part instance from within a Sandboxed
>   Solution.

Please visit the blog post for more information about how you can provision webpart declaratively in modules with the `AllUsersWebPart` element.

Comment: Is there any other way to add webpart to page on sandbox solution programmaticalltically using c# ??